# cannot import class ReduceDocumentsChain

Tags: python, langchain

I am trying to import a library called `ReduceDocumentsChain`, I found out how to import `MapReduceDocumentsChain` but still no luck about the first one.

`from langchain.chains.combine_documents.map_reduce import MapReduceDocumentsChain`

I am following this tutorial:

https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/summarization

Anyone has any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a clean conda environment, installing it through `conda install langchain -c conda-forge` allows me to `from langchain.chains import ReduceDocumentsChain, MapReduceDocumentsChain` without any issues. (this installed langchain v. 0.0.276)

Comment: At the end I did a clean install requirements, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

YOU SHOULD INTALL IT USING THE CORRECT SPELLING .COMMAND IS

pip install ReduceDocumentsChain

then try to import with same name

Comment: Please don't SHOUT AT US. If you need to emphasize something you can [do it with Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).